# Unable to access WebLogic console in container

Tags: docker, containers, weblogic, devops, weblogic12c

I ran a container with WebLogic in it but as want to expose its port, used following command -

```
docker run -it --rm -p 7001:7001 <imagename>
```

to check if console is accessible, made curl request from within the container -

```
curl -I http://localhost:7001/console
```

but it resulted into an error -

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 7001: Connection refused
```

I'm unable to understand what is wrong, please help to understand it.

Comment: Did you check container log?

Comment: Could you check whether this is running by using netstat -anp | grep 7001?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to use Port 9002 with SSL

On my Weblogic Docker Image from Oracle there is a "local Admin Port" configured which overwrites Port 7001 / 7002

Call http**s**://localhost:9002/console

You have to expose port 9002 too

```
docker run -it --rm -p 7001:7001 -p 9002:9002 <image>
```